# Displaying text from ajax call which is passed from controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm struggling to put my error msg "From date must be set before to date", through controller to ajax call. Error message needs to be displayed in div as warning. Code below does not work.

Controller:

```
 $response_array['error'] = [trans('servicereports.errors.to_date')];
 return json_encode($response_array);
```

Result:

> {"error":["From date must be set before to date."]}

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ route('einsight.servicereports.validateDates') }}',
            cache: false,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            error: function(msg, result) {                    
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    $("#error-message").append( value );
                });

            }
        });
```

Div for displaying messages:

```
<div class="flash-message" id="error-message">               
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are handaling error in wrong way. In ajax `error` method will only call if there is error in `ajax` call. till your code execute successfully you have to handle it in success function

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ route('einsight.servicereports.validateDates') }}',
            cache: false,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {                    
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    $("#error-message").append( value );
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: Code in my controller is fine? Because I cannot trigger the error in ajax

Comment: yes its fine error handling can also be done through server side which yiu are doing

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `response(400)->json($data)` to return the JSON with the proper headers:

```
$response_array['error'] = [trans('servicereports.errors.to_date')];
return response(400)->json($response_array);
```

Because you are sending the status code 400, you will trigger your `error` function.  Then you also won't need to parse it because it's known json:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{ route('einsight.servicereports.validateDates') }}',
        cache: false,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        error: function(msg, response) {             
            $.each(response.error, function(index, value) {
                $("#error-message").append( value );
            });

        }
    });
```